# Xamarin - Fake Geolocation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I want to make an app for Xamarin.Forms (mainly iOS) which will fake a Geolocation to the Device so all apps will get a wrong location. I know that this is possible using the simulator but I wonder if this is also possible using a real device and also without being connected to a Mac.

Does anyone know how to do that or is there a library which handles that?

Comment: If you do want to get error Geolocation Info , you can handle them  after getting the correct latitude and longitude, such as increasing or decreasing fixed values.

Comment: Have you got any code as an example? Cause with `Xam.Plugin.Geolocator` the values you get are all readonly

Comment: I don't think this is possible on iOS. At least, there are ways, but you will probably never be able to release it to the App Store. On Android, it might be a bit easier, but you will pretty much hit the same limitations at some point there.

Comment: There is no need for me to release it in AppStore. I is enough to have that app running without beeing connected to the Mac

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how the ios device locate coordinates.

1. GPS
2. Wi-fi
3. Cellurar
4. Bluetooth

You could try to take IP address from different place (vpn). But unfortunately (for you) it will not change it for other apps , just  maybe for some web-applications location.

The simulation of location was made just for testing purpose.

I have no idea how you want to handle your task without jailbreak iOS device.